# How to create Entity with List

Tags: spring, hibernate

I have an entity class named "User", I want to store a list of data in User.

This is my code :

```java
@Entity
public class User extends BaseEntity {
        
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    
    private String firstName;
    
    private String lastName;
    
    @Column(unique = true)
    private String mail;
    
    private String password;
    
    private List<Feature> features;

}
```

And i have a Feature Class but its not a entity because it doesn't need to be an entity class, i think.

```java
public class Feature {
    
    private String fName;
    private Long fYear;

}
```

When I start the application, I get an error:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory; nested exception is org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not determine type for: java.util.List, at table: user, for columns: [org.hibernate.mapping.Column(features)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the `Feature` type does hold instance fields that map to domain data, it should be saved as a separate entity.

If still the `Feature` is out of your domain boundaries and does not need to be stored along the `User`, you can mark it as being `@Transient` and you may need to load its data based on your application semantics when loading a user entity.

Otherwise, you would go a the traditional path of mapping your entity:

```
@Entity
public class Feature extends BaseEntity {

    // ...

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy="features")
    private Set<User> users = new HashSet<>();

    // ...
}
```

Then you would need to define the `User <> Feature` mapping:

```
@Entity    
public class User extends BaseEntity {
            
    // ...
    
    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(name="USER_FEATURE",
        joinColumns=
            @JoinColumn(name="USER_ID", referencedColumnName="ID"),
        inverseJoinColumns=
            @JoinColumn(name="FEATURE_ID", referencedColumnName="ID")
        )
    private Set<Feature> features = new HashSet<>();
    // ...
}
```

Comment: I get this error right now : Unable to map collection com.findemployee.findemployee.entity.User.features

Comment: Would you add the whole exception stack trace?

Answer (score 0):

You can't insert list into SQL table, as a type.

You need to define relation(s):

```
@Entity
public class User extends BaseEntity {
        
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    
    private String firstName;
    
    private String lastName;
    
    @Column(unique = true)
    private String mail;
    
    private String password;
    
    @OneToMany (or any other relation fitting your case)
    private List<Feature> features;

}
```

and

```
@Entity
public class Feature {
   
   @Id
   //define generation strategy here
   private long id;
   
   ​private String fName;
   ​private Long fYear;

}
```